# How do I send a variable from PHP to javascript using Ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

So I have a PHP file where I fetch the data from the database. I also have a JavaScript file where I make an ajax request. Everything is okay, but I'd like to stop the JSON from going on my web page when I echo it. I just want to work with the JSON in Javascript. Here is my code:

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var url = "../../DB/get-data.php";
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      success: function(data){
         var mydata = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
         console.log(mydata);
      }
    });
});
```

**PHP:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY age DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$animals = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $animal = new Animals($row['name'], $row['species'], $row['color'], $row['age']);
  array_push($animals, $animal);
}
echo json_encode($animals);
```

Comment: You are doing something like RESTful API. The php which is being called by javascript means that is able to be public accessed.

Comment: S I assume that you're using the script `get-data.php` in another position in your  project, that it?

Comment: Yes, the structure is something like this: 
root(level 0)
   index.php(level 1)
   DB(level 1)
      get-data.php(level 2)
   Classes(level 1)
      Animals.php(level 2)

Comment: *I'd like to stop the JSON from going on my webpage when I echo it* what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could separate the two files, the file that gets the data without the `echo` :

**get-data.php**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM animals ORDER BY age DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$animals = [];
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $animal = new Animals($row['name'], $row['species'], $row['color'], $row['age']);
  array_push($animals, $animal);
}
```

And another file for the JSON result that implements the echo statement and includes the first one :

**get-data-json.php**

```
include 'you_path_here/get-data.php';

echo json_encode($animals);
```

Then the URL variable in your JS code should call the JSON route like :

```
var url = "../../DB/get-data-json.php";
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you! Could you please explain to me why did this work?

Comment: Since to get the JSON from the ajax request you need to convert your array to JSON using `json_encode($animals);` and show it using `echo`.. when you don't need them in other places when you want just to get the data array from your database. so for that, we create two files one that returns a JSON we will call it in ajax request and another one just getting the data from the database.